# Page breaks when editing a field

Tags: control-panel, field

I'm suddenly having issues with multiple Craft builds on my local dev environment.

[image]

Basically, everything else is working fine but when I edit a field the page breaks. It appears to only be displaying the form with any html, head or body tags. I installed a fresh copy and the issue also occurs on that build. I'm thinking it could be an issue with my version of MAMP or perhaps it's a known issue. Any ideas?

Comment: If you check your browser's console, are you getting any errors?

Comment: I saw this one error. _Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS_ but that doesn't appear to be associated with this problem. That error doesn't show up in other browsers.

Comment: I think that's coming from the AdBlock extension in Chrome. Click on the resources tab and check the response of a CSS or JS file. Is it normal?

Comment: There are no resources being loaded because the page lacks an html, body, and head tags etc. It starts with a form tag.

Comment: I just found this at the bottom of the source code. Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 122880 bytes) in /Users/###/###/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node/Module.php on line 244.

Comment: Ahh... just added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like PHP is running out of memory.  You can edit your php.ini file's [memory_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) setting to something higher than `32M`, which is probably what it's set to right now.  Bump it up to `64M` or `128M` and restart Apache and you should be set.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what it was. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Awesome... no worries!